# gvisGeoMap is processing, but no map displays

Tags: r, google-maps, csv, googlevis

I have a table of data that is 3 columns.  The names of the columns are "country" "Sum.of.Xcelerate.Exp" and "count.of.acctName".  There is data filled out for every country.  I want to plot this data on a geomap so I do

```
test<- read.csv("country_test.csv", header=TRUE)
```

This works ok.  Then I do

```
    plot(gvisGeoMap(test
    , "country"
    , "Sum.of.XcelerateExp"
    ,"Count.of.acctName"
    , options=list(dataMode="markers")))
```

The webpage opens, but there is no map.  It is the same page you would normally see just no map.  Why am I not able to load a map?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you need to be a little more specific about the data you are using if you need a better answer, but I tried to create some data for you that matches the column names you provided

```
require(googleVis)
#simulate some data based on your column names

country=c("Canada","USA","Mexico","Australia")

Sum.of.XcelerateExp=c(50,100,75,25)

Count.of.acctName=c(1,2,3,4)

# put variables into a dataframe called test

test=as.data.frame(list(country=country,
                        Sum.of.XcelerateExp=Sum.of.XcelerateExp,
                        Count.of.acctName=Count.of.acctName))

# create map

plot(gvisGeoMap(test,
                locationvar="country",
                numvar="Sum.of.XcelerateExp",
                hovervar="Count.of.acctName",
                options=list(dataMode="markers")))
```

the plot works on my computer (I'm using Google Chrome), but looking at the help file for gvisGeoMap maybe the problem you're having is your countries are in the wrong format? Format 2 of the locationvar says that it can be a country name. Maybe provide us with the first few rows of your data as well as the structure of your dataset

Try running your script with the following functions so we can get a look at what you're working with:

```
head(test)

str(test)
```